# How do I store Frequent data (Combination of Source-Destination) in Database efficiently to get top10 searches for past 30 Days

Tags: java, mysql, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to write an algorithm which does insert of frequent data search.
Let's say User can search different combination of two entities (Source-Destination), Each time user search I want to store data with count, and if he search same combination(Source-Destination) I will update the count.
In this case if Users are 1000, and if User searches for 0 different combination(Source-Destination) and data will be stored for 30 Days.

So total number of rows will be 100000*30*30=13500000(1.3 Billion) Rows. (using Mysql)

Please suggest me If there is better way to write this.

**GOAL:** I want to get top 10 Searach Combination of users at any point of time.

Comment: There are databases intended for those kinds of purposes, so the easiest way would be to get one of those and use it instead of rolling your own.

Comment: give us an example with a datatable. At the user level or not. How aged. This question is vague. This has nothing to do with java. The best way to get superfluous commentary is to add them into the discussion

Answer (score 0):

`1,000` users and `60,000` rows are nothing by today's standards.  Don't even think about it, there is no performance concern whatsoever, so just focus on doing it properly instead of worrying about slowness.  There will be no slowness.

The proper way of doing it is by creating a table in which each row contains the search terms, ([source,destination] in your case,) and a sum, and using a unique index on the [source, destination] pair of columns.  Which is the same as making those two columns the primary key.

If you had `100,000,000` rows, and performance was critical, and you also had a huge budget affording you the luxury to do whatever weird thing it takes to make ends meet, then you would perhaps want to do something exotic, like appending each search to an indexless table (allowing the fastest appends possible) and then compute the sums in a nightly batch process.  But with less than a million rows such an approach would be a complete overkill.

Edit:

Aha, so the real issue is the OP's need for a "sliding window".  Well, in that case, I cannot see any approach other than saving every single search, along with the time that it happened, and in a batch process a) computing sums, and b) deleting entries that are older than the "window".

Comment: It was Just example, I have data of 1.3 Billion and I want the data very quickly.

Comment: Well, what sense does it make to ask a performance question and give "example numbers" that are wrong by orders of magnitude?  In any case, as you can see, I already edited my answer and I covered the case of a huge dataset, too.

Comment: Mike, a unique index is not a PK. Also to suggest a tablescan can be foolish. Why not suggest a summary table maintained for stats? Or partitioning? Or just not answer:p

Comment: @Drew I did not mention a summary table because I thought that the OP already understands that they will need this.  But you are right, maybe he does not.  So I will amend my answer. And I did not say that a unique index is a PK, I only said that a unique index on those two fields (of the summary table, of course) are as good as a primary key.

Comment: I understand the data is not too much , but is there any way/algorithm not to write even this much data into database. as I need only top 10 Search Counts. Its Like sliding window algorithm.

Comment: This question needs a schema answer. That means best to present one. Else it is just silly :p

Comment: @user2888996 I amended my answer with a solution to your specific need.

Comment: @Drew if the OP had given a schema question, I would have given a schema answer.